# Making python library from C

Tags: tensorflow, cmake

I am trying to work with source Tensorlow.Its library which was implemented in C and then can be compilied to some languages,so I need to make python lib.
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/contrib/cmake

Here is the guide how to 2 it,but last command takes too much time.

**D:...\build> MSBuild /p:Configuration=Release tf_python_build_pip_package.vcxproj**

How can I update project quickly if I changed only one C file?
I read about BAZEL before but for I cant make this working, so I need cmake solution.

Comment: Once you fully generated you .vcxproj file, updating should be fast. Did you actually wait until it was finished (you say it takes 'too much time')?

Comment: Yes,first time about 3 hours,next are close to it

Comment: So doesn't that answer your question? I'm not sure what you're looking for..

Comment: What's the issue with Bazel? For iterative development it's quite nice, and I believe our Bazel build has some Windows support.

Comment: bazel is always falls with strange errors, which are not answered in tensorflow github,most answers are like "try ubuntu better", so I just want to make faster cmake building